Extra Row with csvreader in tabularx
I have problems with the formatting of a tabularx environment when I import data via csvreader.
When the table imports data via csvreader an unnecessary extra row is started at the end of the import.
If the table is described further, it is formatted correctly.
But now I want my table to end at the end of the import.
The \hlines are unfortunately necessary for later formatting in the table.
The CSV-File looks like this:
This is a simplified representation of the csv file.
Header1 ; Header2 ; Header3 
25,46 ; 25 ; 0,46 
25,46 ; 25 ; 0,46 

I don't know how I could avoid a possible empty last line during the import.
Code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{10 cm}{|X|X|X|}
        \hline
        \csvreader[head to column names, separator=semicolon]{data.csv}{}{
            \csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii \\ \hline 
        }
%       1 & 2 & 3\\
%       \hline  
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}


A short addition to the command \csvcol.
\csvcoli Refers to the respective column to be read in. After the command, the column number is specified in a Roman numeral.
For example: Column 3 in Excel “C” would be '\csvcoliii' here.
Example1:
This shows the extra row.

Example2:
If the line "1&2&3\" ist added to the code the table is formed well.

I would be very grateful for your help.

please supply a sample data file and definitions of \csvcolii 

don't use an external link that will break over time *the question is archived here forever) please edit the question so the posted code is a complete small document that shows the problem

I have added the definition of the \csvcol command.
The definition of the CSV file was already included in the document. I have not yet succeeded in creating a “better” visualization with the editor.

So your "csv" file isn't comma separated but | separated values? I tried saving the file you show as data.csv  but your example still stops with the error  ! Undefined control sequence. \csv@@body -> \csvcoli & \csvcolii

Your code shows separator=semicolon but the data file you show has no ; ??

sigh I fixed your example this time, you want ; and newlines as the separators to get the output shown

This is correct. You have edited the file correctly. Thank you very much.
I wanted to use the website editor to create a table as described in the example. Unfortunately, this was not implemented correctly.

website formatting is the last thing we need, just need to see the source required to show the problem. (that's why I asked how to define csvcolii in the first comment as I got that error when I guessed a csv file with commas)

the csvsimple looping adds some tokens that start a new (visually empty) cell at the end, so you can put the newline at the start of each iteration (except the first)

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{10 cm}{|X|X|X|}
  \hline
        \csvreader[head to column names, separator=semicolon]{data.csv}{}{
         \csviffirstrow{}{\\\hline}  \csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii
       }%
       \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}

